# KeyError 'R', defining a function

Tags: python, keyerror

I am getting

```
Failed example:
    distances('Raleigh', 'Centreville', cities)
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\agsmi\anaconda3\lib\doctest.py", line 1336, in __run
        exec(compile(example.source, filename, "single",
      File "<doctest __main__.distances[0]>", line 1, in <module>
        distances('Raleigh', 'Centreville', cities)
      File "C:\Users\agsmi\Desktop\st114\homework5.py", line 110, in distances
        return (6371 * (math.acos(math.sin(cities[city1[0]]) * math.sin(cities[city2[0]]) + math.cos(cities[city1[0]]))) * math.cos(cities[city2[0]]) * math.cos(cities[city1[1]] - cities[city2[1]])), ((math.sqrt(cities[city2[0]] - cities[city1[0]]**2 + cities[city2[1]] - cities[city1[1]]))**2)
    KeyError: 'R'
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   2 in __main__.distances
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

From this code

```
def distances(city1:str, city2:str, cities:dict):
    """
    Description: Takes in two strings (city1 and city2), searches to see if those strings are found in the cities dictionary. If they are, this calculates the great circle distance and the Euclidean distance between the cities.
        
    >>> distances('Raleigh', 'Centreville', cities)
    ***
    >>> distances('NYC', 'Tianjin', cities)
    (nan, nan)
    
    """
    cities = {'Raleigh':(35.7796, -78.6382), 'Tianjin':(39.129498, 117.251038), 'Centreville':(32.9446, -87.1386), 'Los Angeles':(34.0522, -118.2437), 'Houston':(29.749907, -95.358421)}
    import math
    
    if city1 in cities and city2 in cities:
        return (6371 * (math.acos(math.sin(cities[city1[0]]) * math.sin(cities[city2[0]]) + math.cos(cities[city1[0]]))) * math.cos(cities[city2[0]]) * math.cos(cities[city1[1]] - cities[city2[1]])), ((math.sqrt(cities[city2[0]] - cities[city1[0]]**2 + cities[city2[1]] - cities[city1[1]]))**2)
        
    else:
        return(math.nan, math.nan)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Other stuff is probably wrong with the code too, but I am confused about this right now. I am a beginner and this is for an assignment that asks for:

Following the function design recipe, define a function distances that takes in two strings
city1 and city2 and a dictionary cities as parameters. The dictionary cities has
city names as keys and tuples of (latitude, longitude) as their values. The function returns a
tuple of two items. (You do not need to include examples in your docstring.)

• If city1 and city2 are in the dictionary cities then the first item in the returned
tuple is the great-circle distance between city1 and city2 and the second item in
the returned tuple is the Euclidean distance between city1 and city2.

I don't know why I am getting this error.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher i added it now

Comment: @SravanJS thank you I didn't know about that, I changed that now. I am still getting the error though

Comment: what is `city1[0]`? is the first letter of key, by example: `distances('Raleigh', 'Centreville', cities)` then `city1[0]` is `R`

Comment: @eyllanesc ohhh that makes sense! I am trying to get it to take the numbers associated with each key, so for city1[0] I would want 35.7796. How would i do that?

Comment: In every place change **cities [cityx][value]**

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is that you take the first character from the string, and not the first value from the tuple:

You have so:

```
cities[city1[0]] - > 'Raleight'[0] - > 'R' (key: 'R')
```

Try to do this:

```
cities[city1][0]
```

And do this with everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting R from first letter of from parameter if you put "Houston" instead of then you will get H so it show indexing error please find out by subtract source city key to destination key or multiply as per your mathematical way.